# Using mysql & pools in node.js in a cleaner way?

Tags: mysql, node.js, connection-pooling

I would like to know if there is a more shorter or elegant way to do mysql requests in node.js (using pools)

Actually this is how i do multiple requests (i simplified the code for the example, see my comments inside) :

```
var Mysql = require('mysql');

//Creating the pool of sql connections
var Pool = Mysql.createPool({
    host: Config.database.auth.host,
    user: Config.database.auth.user,
    password: Config.database.auth.pass,
    name: Config.database.auth.name
});

//Using one of the connections available in the pool
PoolAuth.getConnection(function (e, c) {

    if (e) {

        //failed to use the connection

    } else {

        //Executing the first query
        c.query("SELECT * FROM blabla WHERE id = ?", [1], function (e, r, f) {

            //Releasing the connection, should i do that at this moment or before closing the pool ?
            c.release();


            if (e) {

                //failed to exe the query

            }
            else {

               //Executing second query
               c.query("UPDATE blabla SET  enabled = ? WHERE id= ?", [1, r[0].id], function (e, r, f) {});

            }
        });
    }
});
```

It would be more elegant and clean to be able to do something like this :

```
var query = Pool->query("SELECT * FROM blabla WHERE id=?", [0]);
if(query) {
    Pool->query("UPDATE blabla SET enabled = ? WHERE id=?", [1, query.id]);
}
```

(similar to what i would do in PHP)

Thanks for your help

Comment: Pool.query(sql, placeholders, callback)

Comment: @hlfrmn : If i use `Pool.query(sql, placeholders, callback)`, i'm afraid that it will get a connection and use it for every others requests i do like this (aka not releasing the connection used). Or am i wrong?

Comment: `pool.query` is a shortcut for what you're doing; It releases connection automatically.

Comment: Perfect then, thank you!